# Necessary condition for the induced topology to be Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a continuous map.
If $f$ is proper then $f(X)\subseteq Y$ is Hausdorff.
However $f$ need not be proper for $f(X)$ to be Hausdorff. So what must $f$ be? If $X$ is compact then $f$ must be proper, so I guess my question is:

**Question:** Let $X$ be non-compact and $f:X\to Y$ continuous. If $f(X)$ with the induced topology is Hausdorff then $f$ satisfies what?

Comment: Since $1$-point subspaces trivially inherit a Hausdorff topology, then any constant map $f:X\to Y$ works. Given that, I suspect not much can be concluded about $f$.